# Full CRUD app without a database possible?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

If I use a json file stored in one of my GitHub repos as a mock backend, I know how to fetch and read all the data. Is it also possible to edit or post new data to this json file? Would an alternative mock backend like Mocky.io be a better solution (to achieve full CRUD)?

Comment: Is it technically possible? Sure. Is it a good idea? Almost certainly not. (Technically, you'd just be inventing your own bad database, anyways. It'd still be *a database*.)

Comment: It looks like is for demo purposes, In that case, yes you can, also there's in memory database solutions (usually used for mocking or running tests) that can persist data into a file, something like this maybe https://www.npmjs.com/package/nano-sql.

Comment: yes, the app i made was for demo purposes. What your thoughts on using a Google Sheet instead of the json file in GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could store the information inside csv files or somehting like that, you would be recreating a database engine as MongoDB & create your own reader to find the info, or you could store the users info using local Storage,
However this would make your app very limited.

Here's the link for the documentation of local storage

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to try out CRUD operations you can use free JSON APIs like http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ or
https://mockfirst.com/

where you can create, read, update and delete data using various api end points. It is better to go this way first then you could move on to updating a JSON file.

---

(UPDATE)

You can use https://jsonbin.io/

Here you can place your own data and use it as an API.

Comment: Thanks. I am familiar w/ jsonplaceholder. I wanted to use my own data instead of their pre-populated data (posts, users). Mockfirst looks interesting.